# Append Jquery Ajax "data" as separate values in a table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables, append

I have a table as the following datatable table :

```
            <button id="addRow">Add New Row</button><br>
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover "  id="example" cellSpacing=0 width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>1</th>
                            <th>2</th>
                            <th>3</th>
                            <th>4</th>
                            <th>5</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tr style="text-align: center;">
                        <td>hola</td>
                        <td>ciao</td>
                        <td>bonjour</td>
                        <td>yo</td>
                        <td>salut</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

I'd like to append elements using a javascript script as the following :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            debugger;
                            var t = $('#example').DataTable({ "searching": true, "paging": true });
                        var counter = 1;
                        $('#addRow').on('click', function ciicici() {

                        var now = new Date();
                        var now = now.toMysqlFormat();
                        var tii = new Date();
                        tii.setSeconds(tii.getSeconds() - 50000);
                        var tii = tii.toMysqlFormat();
                        $.post( "sqlmachine_test_ajax.php", {  timing: now,seconding: tii  })
                        .done(function( data ) {
                                t.row.add([
                                counter +'.1',
                                counter +'.2',
                                counter +'.3',
                                counter +'.4',
                                counter +'.5'
                                ]).draw();
                                counter++;
                            // });  
                            //setTimeout(function(){ciicici();}, 5000);
                        }); // Automatically add a first row of data
                        $('#addRow').click();
                    });
                </script>
```

The two are working properly, the only thins is that I'd like to retreive the elements to append trough an Jquery AJAX script.

Let's say I have a php page sending back 5 values I'd like to add to each column (instead of the counter1, counter2 etc...) as the following :

```
<?php
echo 'counter1, counter2, counter3, counter4, counter5';
?>
```

and in the javascript I wanted to put simply :

```
...
.done(function( data ) {
                                    t.row.add([
                                    data //(instead of the counters)
                                    ]).draw();
                                    counter++;
...
```

I have tried this, as well as arrays and json encoded arrays, but all I get is the 5 results in the same first cell of the table. 
So how could I append the ajax php response to a table as data in different cells of the table?

marko

Comment: You might want to edit to note in the subject, that you are using Datatables, which is different from simply appending to an HTML table.

Comment: Add JQuery tag please. Javascript is not JQuery. JQuery is some lib I don't want to touch or debug.

Comment: thanks I have added both datatable and jquery

Comment: Someone's on a high horse...  Javascript elitist up there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get your data back from the call, you have to separate using `.split()`.

so you can do this when you get your callback

```
.done(function( data ) {
    var splitData = data.split(", ") //Split your data with the comma and space
    $.each(splitData, function(e){  //For each piece of data
        //Add your rows here one by one
        t.row.add([
            splitData[e] //Make sure the 'e' in the function and here are the same
        ]).draw();
    })
    counter++;
});
```

This a loose answer, I'll try to add more soon.

Edit:  More info

what I normally do is echo everything with separators.  So, in your case, I would echo `1, 2, 3, 4, 5:A, B, C, D, E`.  So when the data returns, that's what you'll see.

In your data success, you would do something like

```
var dataParts = data.split(":") //This splits your data into the 2 parts using the : separator
var dataPart1 = dataParts[0] //This will get 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
var dataPart2 = dataParts[1] //this will get A, B, C, D, E
```

Then from there, you split using commas.

```
var dataPieces1 = dataPart1.split(', ');
var dataPieces2 = dataPart2.split(', ');
```

Then run the loops. (using javascript's `for` loop is usually better than using jQuery's `.each()`)

```
for(var i = 0; i < dataPieces1.length; i++){ //Start your for loop on the first part
    //Create a row here using dataPieces1[i], this will loop and make a new
    //row every time the next loop finishes
    for(var j = 0; j < dataPieces2.length; j++){ //Start the second loop
        //Not sure how you would want to do this, but here's some example code
        //Since you're inside a row now, append your dataPieces2[j] to that row
        //This will loop for every dataPieces2 and append each one as a column
        //in that single row.
    } 
}
```

Comment: hey thanks, seems working but I'd have 2 points. as you suggest new lines are appended, not new columns. Plus if I had several lines and several columns to append how would I do that? I imagine I'd have to send an array structured in several lines and several columns. imagine for example that my php file would be as echo "1,2,3,4,5", echo "6,7,8,9,10"; I'd like to append this 2 rows to the table together.

Comment: any ideas how to do that?

Comment: @markoc. Sorry about the delay.  I'll add a response in the answer above